# How to show a <tag> inside a text tag e.g <p>,<div>,etc?

Tags: html

I want to show `<script>` as text from the `<p>` tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title id="Pestaña">Pestaña</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <p id="demo">  a <script> tag </p>
    <h6>A Web Page</h6>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just encode the opening bracket like `&lt;` so that your browser doesn't interpret it as a tag. You can do the closing bracket too with `&gt;` but it's unnecessary. e.g.

```html
 <p id="demo">  a &lt;script> tag </p>
```